# How to modify virtual host conf file in apache 2.4 to include ip access (Require ip) restrictions for forwarded subdomain

Tags: apache, security, webserver, virtualhost, apache2.4

I have following conf file which is supposed to take a subdomain URL and repoint it to a local port on the server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.mysite.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/gui(/?)(.*)$ /$2 [PT]
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/gui/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080
</VirtualHost>
```

The reformatting works correctly and entering subdomain.mysite.com redirects to the service running on port 8080 on my server. However I am now looking to restrict access by IP through using the require ip command however no variation I use is working.

When using a require ip directly in the virtual host tag I get the error that require cannot be used in the virtualhost context and when I try and use the location directive that loads the conf file fine however it doesn't seem to do any form of ip filtering.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<Proxy "http://127.0.0.1:8080/path">
  Require ip 192.168.0.123
</Proxy>
```

Comment: many thanks, worked like a charm. however could someone please explain why the redirect address has to be redefined in the proxy directive when its has proxy pass defined. would it work without the redirect address as a single proxy tag with the access rules imbedded.